# Flutter error on running application on google chrome, edge

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, runtime-error

I am not able to run the basic flutter application on google chrome as there is an option for google chrome, edge, and avd.

[image]

Comment: please, run flutter doctor and add the output to the question, to see what is the problem, so you could get help faster

Answer (score 0):

to add web support to an existing app

run `flutter create .` in the application terminal

to run it on chrome for example run `flutter run -d chrome`